# Hausdorff compact with closed function

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and let $f$ be continuous, closed, surjective function from $X$ to $Y$. Prove that $Y$ is Hausdorff.

It is obvious that $Y$ is Hasudorff space. However, I have trouble to get the right answer.

Comment: You are saying that it is obvious but you can't formally prove it? Or what are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Let $y_0$ and $y_1$ be distinct points of $Y$, and let $F_0=f^{-1}[\{y_0\}]$ and $F_1=f^{-1}[\{y_1\}]$.

- $F_0$ and $F_1$ are closed in $X$; why?
- $F_0\ne\varnothing\ne F_1$; why?
- $X$ is normal; why?

Let $U_0$ and $U_1$ be disjoint open nbhds of $F_0$ and $F_1$, respectively.

- Show that $Y\setminus f[X\setminus U_1]$ and $Y\setminus f[X\setminus U_0]$ are disjoint open nbhds of $y_0$ and $y_1$, respectively, and conclude that $Y$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: what is wrong wirh my answer?

Comment: @Leonardo: I hadn’t even checked yours when I added mine: I did so because I thought that there should be an answer that uses the definition of *Hausdorff* and doesn’t require having already proved that a space is Hausdorff iff every convergent net in the space has a unique limit. However, there is a problem with yours, which I identified in my comment below it.